# Save/retrieve Image from SQL database using ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql, image, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a legacy SQL database that has an Image column that I need to display images from in an `<img/>` control. Any help would be appreciated!

Mike

Comment: Which **RDBMS** is this for? "SQL" is just a **language** - not a database system - and it often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to display an image in an HTML img tag, follow these steps:

1. Create an ASP.NET controller for returning images, let's name it `ImageController`
2. The `ImageController` will have an action method responsible for calling the database to get the image byte array (a.k.a. `byte[]`), let's call it `GetImage()`
3. The `GetImage()` method must return an [`File(byte[], string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.file?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_File_System_Byte___System_String_)
4. Now, point the source of the HTML `img` tag to the `ImageController`, `GetImage()` method and you are done:

   ```
   <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "ImageController")"/>
   ```